# When you have P( A | B ) don't you always have to multiply by the chance of B occurring (P(B))?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

This question is in reference to the equation 3.2.26 that is given as

$$ P(B,A,G,W) = P(A|B)\,P(B)\,P(W|A)\,P(G|A) $$

I would have thought that is should be

$$ P(B,A,G,W) = P(A|B)\,P(B)\,P(W|A)\,P(G|A)\,P(A) $$

Why isn't there a  $P(A)$ there? Is my assumption that you always multiply by the chance of the evidence occurring wrong? Or is it the assumption that P(A) = 1, because Dr Watson said so?

[image: BN = Belief network]

Comment: I slightly edited your question. Please note some of our users may be visually impaired so they wouldn't be able to read the formulas pasted as a picture. Also notice that this site enables users to use $\TeX$ formatting for formulas.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks. I'm not really sure how to use TEX on here even though I know the language, is there a quick guide for implementation?

Comment: Just put your latex stuff within dollar signs (single for in line, double for display) and you're good to go.  Click edit to see how Tim pulled it off for some examples.

Comment: You can always ask on http://tex.stackexchange.com and you can find multiple tutorials online. For formula to display put it between `$` for inlien formula, e.g. `$E(x)$` is $E(X)$, or between `$$`, e.g. `$$E(X)$$` would be a formula in it's own line.

Comment: Btw, drawing a graph would help, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215034/bayesian-errors-in-variables-model-definition-in-jags-and-symbolically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $P(A)$ you're looking for is already in the formula, in the form of $P(A|B)P(B)$. The Bayesian network has A dependent on B, and W and G both dependent on A. We can get the overall probability of A using the chain rule to compute $P(A|B)P(B)$. Then, the chain rule is applied again to get $P(W)$ and $P(G)$ from $P(W|A)P(G|A)P(A)$