# How to calculate probability of Bayes network?

Tags: probability, data-mining, bayesian-network

Hi I'm new into Bayes network

I'm trying to calculate P(F&G) but don't have the slightest clue how because everything i find online doesn't have a network that is this complex. [image]

I will really grateful with any help with this. I've been stuck here for so long.

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215034/bayesian-errors-in-variables-model-definition-in-jags-and-symbolically/215043#215043

Comment: Hi i had a look at the link but still don't have a clue. Could you possibly start me on the right path?